# Submit form only if at least one checkbox is checked using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following form:
https://expogr.com/bankexpokenya/advertise.php

I am filling the details of the form and clicking on the submit button. If I have not checked one checkbox, it gives me a message saying "please select any one checkbox" along with the `ok` button.
After clicking the `ok` button, the form is getting submitted. For form submission, I have used email method so the form data is sent to the particular emailids.

I have tried the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(){
        if ($('input:checkbox').filter(':checked').length < 1){
            alert("Please select at least one option from above!");
            break;
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

But its not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(){
        if ($('input:checkbox').filter(':checked').length < 1){
            alert("Please select at least one option from above!");
            break;
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a question or problem description here.  What is the difference between these two code samples?  Which one are you using?  How is it failing?

Comment: `break` does nothing except inside a loop, so it shouldn't be there. The `return false` should be working though.

Comment: @RobinZigmond..i tried using e.preventDefault();....after using that also form is getting submitted from back..

Comment: Please try with ctrl+f5 and check. I have tested your link and its working as expected. Code also seems correct. Just `break;` doesn't do anything. It should be removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with the `break` statement, remove that and your code will work as expected.  Also, you do not need to use `.filter()` separately as you can specify `:checked` as part of the selector:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form").submit(function(){
    if ($('input:checkbox:checked').length < 1){
      alert("Please select at least one option from above!");
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="checkbox"/>First
  <input type="checkbox"/>Second
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

You can also try  with [`Event​.prevent​Default()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form").submit(function(e){
    if ($('input:checkbox:checked').length < 1){
      alert("Please select at least one option from above!");
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="checkbox"/>First
  <input type="checkbox"/>Second
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the break statement.see the below mentioned code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("form").submit(function(){
        if ($('input:checkbox').filter(':checked').length < 1){
            alert("Please select at least one option from above!");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```